# PHP readdir, glob and exec('ls') return in an empty array for some directories under Apache

Tags: php, apache, glob, ls, readdir

I have developed the following PHP code in order to read a specific directory called `/dados/capture`:

`tst2.php`

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "whoami: " . shell_exec('whoami')."<br>\n";
exec('ls /dados/capture/',$base);
echo "/dados/capture content ...<br>\n";
foreach ( $base as $dir )
{
    print $dir ."<br>\n";
}
?>
```

Executing the code through linux command line "[root$mysite]# sudo -u apache php tst2.php" returns the following:

```
<html>
<body>
whoami: apache
<br>
/dados/capture content ...<br>
120130312115149.jpg<br>
120130312115149.swf<br>
120130312115658.jpg<br>
120130312115658.swf<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Calling `tst2.php` from web browser results in:

```
whoami: apache 
/dados/capture content ...
```

I have tried changing the permission for the folder(s) and creating directive `<directory><directory>` in `httpd.conf`, without any change to the result.

I have tested the code with different directory it was a surprise, because it also doesn't work for `/boot`, `/mnt` and `/opt` directories.

Using `glob` or `readdir` result the same, but consumes much more processor.

I'm using CentOs 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.i686, Apache/2.2.15 and PHP 5.4.12.

Did someone have a similar problem?

Comment: if you could place your code in codeblocks please. to use a codeblock leave 4 spaces

Comment: It seems a permissions problem. On the command line you are running the script as root. The apache server user probably has not enough rights to list the folder

Answer (score 0):

Try
    $out = shell_exec('ls /dir/path 2>&1');
The user who is browsing the web may not have permission. So, you **may be getting** this error.